Установка recaptcha v3
Внедряю reCaptcha v3 в форму отправки запроса на перезвонить. Форма реализована на ajax. Конструкция такова
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=мой_сайт_кей"></script>
...
<form class="t-form" id="feedback" action="">                                               
    <input type="text" class="t-input" name="phone" id="phone" type="tel" autocomplete="tel">
    <button type="submit" class="t-submit">Жду звонка</button>
</form>

Javascript
function resetForm() {
    $('#feedback')[0].reset();
}
 
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('button[type="submit"]').click(function(){
 
        $('#feedback').validate({
        rules: {
             phone: {
                required: true,
            },
        },
        messages: {
            phone: {
                required: 'Укажите номер телефона',
            },
        },
 
        submitHandler: function(){
             sendAjaxForm('feedback', 'mail.php'); 
             return false; 
        }
        });
    });
 
                function sendAjaxForm(feedback, url) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url:      "./mail.php",
                                    type:     "POST", 
                                    dataType: "html", 
                                    data: $("#"+feedback).serialize(),  
                                    success: function(response) { 
                                        
                                                                             всё ОК
 
                                        });
                                    resetForm();
                                    },
                                    error: function(response) { // Данные не отправлены
                                        
                                                                             всё плохо
                                                                          
                                        });
                                    resetForm();
                                    }
                                });
 
                }
});

mail.php
 if (isset($_POST["phone"])) { 
     
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; 
     
    $to = 'name@mydomen.ru'; // Куда отправляем
    $from = 'noreply@mydomen.ru'; // От кого отправляем
    $subject = "Запрос обратного звонка"; 
    $message = "Телефон: $phone\n";
    $headers = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $from\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $from\r\n";  
     
    $send = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }

Как правильно установить капчу, что-бы она запускалась после проверки введен ли номер (required: 'Укажите номер телефона',)
если в js добавляю
    function resetForm() {
    $('#feedback')[0].reset();
}
 
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('button[type="submit"]').click(function(){
        $('#feedback').validate({
            rules: {
                phone: {
                    required: true,
                },
            },
 
            messages: {
                phone: {
                    required: '<br><span style="display: block;margin-top: -10px;">Укажите номер телефона</span>',
                },
            },
            
            submitHandler: function(){
                 sendAjaxForm('feedback', 'mail.php'); //Вызываем функцию отправки формы
                 return false; 
            }
        });
    });
 
   function onClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            grecaptcha.execute('мой_сайт_кей', {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) {
 
 
          
                function sendAjaxForm(feedback, url) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url:      "./mail.php", //url страницы 
                        type:     "POST", //метод отправки
                        dataType: "html", //формат данных
                        data: $("#"+feedback).serialize(),  // Сеарилизуем объекты формы
                        success: function(response) { //Данные отправлены успешно
                            swal.fire({
                                title: "Успешно отправлено!",
                                icon: "success",
                                showConfirmButton: false,
                                timer: 3000
                            });
                            resetForm();
                        },
                        error: function(response) { // Данные не отправлены
                            swal.fire({
                                title: "Ошибка отправления!",
                                icon: "error",
                                showConfirmButton: false,
                                timer: 3000
                            });
                            resetForm();
                        }
                    });
                }
                
    
            });
        });
    }
    
});

а в php
if (isset($_POST["phone"])) { 
    $secret_key = 'мой_секрет_кей';
 
 
    function getCaptcha($s){
        $response = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret_key."&response={$s}"); 
        return json_decode($response);
    }
    
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; 
    $to = 'zhuckss@gmail.com'; // Куда отправляем
    $from = 'noreply@bookvary.ru'; // От кого отправляем
    $subject = "Запрос обратного звонка"; 
    $message = "Телефон: $phone\n";
    $headers = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $from\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $from\r\n";  
    $send = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}

не работает =(
при этом если в index добавляю
<input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse">

то вижу, что токен получает
